# Enable or disable scheduled jobs in Spring Boot based on Database Value

Tags: spring-boot, cron, polling

Ihave to scheduled jobs with cron style patterns in Spring Boot application, using the @Scheduled annotation.

I have used the cron jobs before where cron pattern is stored in a config properties file. But in this case I want to disable my cron job when a flag which is maintained in Database turns true. Something like this I want to acheive.

Or Is there any other way of disable database polling when the required state is reached?

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty("yourConditionDBPropery")
public class SchedulingService {

//Run this task when flag in DB is set to true
@Scheduled
public void task1() {...}

@Scheduled
public void task2() {...}

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring @Conditional based on a value in database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61537318/spring-conditional-based-on-a-value-in-database-table)

Answer (score 1):

According to Baeldung, the [conditional property](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-enabled-conditionally) comes from configuration, not database.

I would suggest something like this :

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty("yourConditionDBPropery")
public class SchedulingService {

//Run this task when flag in DB is set to true
@Scheduled
public void task1() {
    if(flag) {
        ....
    }
}

@Scheduled
public void task2() {...}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to turn off my cron job based on DB value I can check the Databse value using if but why to receive non-required cron job hits whole day ? Any way to enable or disable database polling?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by loading the database property during the life cycle.

There are multiple ways.

1. Implementing the EnvironmentAware Interface
2. Implementing the EnvironmentPostProcessor Interface

and others too.

By the above implementations, you need to load the propertysources and use them in the class as @Value Annotation.

Moreover, You need to use @DependsOn Annotation on the class matching/referencing the @Component Annotation where PropertySources are loaded.

However, I observed that @ConditionOnProperty/@ConditionalOnExpression evaluation on a class by the first approach, do have a problem but can @value Annotation works perfectly fine.

And second approach, it works fine but you need a Manual JDBC connection & statement execution along with the PropertySources loading. Here Spring JPA/JDBC doesn't work out due to life cycle.

Hope this clarifies your question.